# Howto mix raw Webgl with THREE.js

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl, render-to-texture

I am trying to use an "existing" Webgl screen (I'll call it S2) - logic which I do not want to migrate to THREE.js - to produce a dynamic texture that I can use in some THREE.js based (R47) screen (I'll call it S1).

The only thing which I succeded to do was to render S1 & S2 into two separate canvas instances (using 2 separate WebGl context instances) and just overlay the results:
http://www.wothke.ch/webglTests/MixWebGlTest.htm

Various other approaches did not work: 
 - First I tried to let the S2 render into separate framebuffer (rather that in the screen) and then use the respective texture directly in S1. (see initTextureFramebuffer(w, h) in wavefront.js file..)

- when that failed I tried to let S1 grab the data from the separate canvas that S2 had output its data to. (see getTextureFromCanvas (ctx, c) in scrolltext.js) - this logic is still active in the above version (in addition to the simple overlay) but as can be seen on the cube in the center, the texture is actually fetched from the wrong canvas..)
- experiments with using either the same gl instance (i.e. reusing the one created by THREE.js) or having separate instances did not lead to success. I had the impression that as soon as a shared instance was used, THREE.js would corrupt the stuff that had been setup by the plain WebGL logic..

What can I do to get a correct texture from S2 that I can then use in S1?

Comment: You need to create some type of object that Three.js could work with. So THREE.Pass, THREE.Texture, any type that you could later on use in Three.js code.

Comment: That's why I've been using a THREE.Texture (see code above).. it's just that so far the respective wiring does not seem to work..